# How to catch "action" link after submitting web form?

Tags: linux, browser, forms, addons

There is a login panel on bank site, and I'm trying to fetch/catch "action link" after (button press) submitting a form.

Site is using https and some js scripts, that makes effort to read all of them and figure out, plus each site has their own scripts and other techniques and they change a lot. I am trying to find a way to make it easier to catch than reading all the html/js code.

I am not trying to harm anyone, just want to get my data with auto login to many (about 5) sites at once.

I was using strace but without any success, then i heard that wireshark has ability to decode SSL but no success here either.

**Is there any chance to catch "action link" that browser is sending?**

I have idea to put server and redirect my outgoing connection to my server, and catch those request there but it will take to much time for me, so trying to find "simple/faster" way. Maybe some browsers/add-ons already has one of those functionalities?

Thank you for any ideas.

---

15/01/2012 14:12 Well i used **firefox & firebug** to debug with suggestion of **slhck**, i found that f&f current crash when touching scripts - so couldn't do much, for now I'm giving myself a chill. I will turn to this problem again - cause now it generates more problems than solutions.
I don't want to install chrome because of my personal feelings. Back in the day i was using **greasemonkey** for browser interaction.

@lastpass: i need that "action link" for my program that fetch data from site and presents in readable sheet, couldn't find source of lastpass to eventually mod it to my purposes.

---

15/01/2012 15:23 UNTESTED It is not the solution i want but: there is a way to open x window with web frame, load in this frame page, then program will fill login/pass and click what is needed to be clicked in this x window webframe, then copy data from loaded page. But is about to use X that i don't want to use, but on the other hand i don't need to know action link to do this operation. I'm facing compromise here.

---

29/01/2012 11:20
Used GreaseMonkey scripts http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Web_Forms to inject code and read form post data, but another failure. Anyway if someone want to do something similar, it should be fine to do it with GM. On Bank site, it was for me to hard to do it, because there was a dummy form, dummy js, and somewhere was created another form and the real js was compressed whole source "full" obscurity. I could reverse it but that was not my point to do it ... its time for 1st idea: to put some proxy and catch link on wire.

---

08/08/2012 15:15
I found that seamonkey has pageinfo (ctrl+i) tab Forms. It will show all forms on the site (but only before submitting a form). So, it should be possible to freeze web page after submitting and check pageinfo again.

For me, Proxy was the solution.

Comment: Well, if it uses Javascript, you can use Chrome's debugger tools to set a breakpoint in the scripts themselves, but that would mean you need to go through the code. Especially if it's a compressed, dynamically generated Javascript, good luck with that ..

Comment: By the way, [Lastpass.com](http://lastpass.com) will offer to save autofilled passwords when forms are sent, so you could theoretically use this and then export them from the LastPass Vault.

Comment: @slhck : after reading word breakpoint something pop up im my mind, the easiest solution would probably be (what you wrote) to insert/inject own js code into browser trough debuger, because almost all or all sites returns onsubmit function. So envelope onSubmit="return function()" with own_function(return function()) and open new tab with reading all data fields from form. Trying it out thank you. :)